# Lithium battery consuming more power on Sleep Mode

Tags: microcontroller, power, pic, batteries, embedded

I am trying to reduce the power consumption for [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778b.pdf) on sleep mode. The PIC is drawing about .01 mA (6 uA) on sleep mode with Alkaline AAA batteries and other power source, but when I use Lithium batteries the power consumption is higher. It starts low then ramps up all the way to 1.06 mA and remains at that level. I am not quite sure what's different about Lithium batteries that's causing higher current consumption durning sleep mode, maybe someone can shed some lights.

Thanks!

**Lithium Battery Specification**
[image]

Comment: How are you powering this from the lipo?  Hopefully not directly, as the maximum supply voltage of that chip is 3.6v and your lipo will deliver most of its useful capacity from 4.2v down to 3.7v.  How many AAA cells do you use for that test?  How are you measuring the current?  It's not trivial to measure in a way that does not disturb the experiment.

Comment: I am powering the chip directly since it can have a max voltage of 4.2. I used 2 AAA batteries, and I using an amp meter to measure the current.

Comment: Well, that is your first mistake. Section 27.1 of the data sheet you link gives 3.6v as the maximum.  Using an amp meter to measure the current is the second mistake - on a scale where the internal loss is low enough to operate the processor and get it into sleep mode, you probably won't be able to measure the sleep current, and on a scale where you can measure the sleep current the internal loss (burden voltage, if not I*R) will probably be too high to allow the processor to boot and enter sleep mode.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out, let me do another test with less voltage supply and see what happens.

Comment: Chris, how would you propose measuring such a small amount of current without your setup affecting the measurement? I am curious. Is there a way to measure how much current has flowed over a long time period to get some sort of precision gain from averaging perhaps?

Comment: I think I might have done something crude with a jumper lead across a micro-amp scale meter to allow it to boot, which I then removed once I thought it was in sleep mode.   There have been circuits published for low burden voltage microamp meters, too. Generally I wasn't trying to actually measure the sleep mode current exactly, but to verify that I was in that mode and not a higher consumption one.  Remember to watch out for power leaking in via communications or debug cables!  Another idea could be to boot it, go into sleep, pull the power, and watch the decline of the filter capacitors.

Comment: @Nick: http://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing that link. I've already reshared it some team members who are facing this same issue now of trying to eek out every little bit of battery life. You could really post that as an answer to this question. I know that this is kind of a 'product recommendation' thing though.

Comment: Do you have the REGSLP bit set? See section 24.3.4... Also, as noted above the part is not rated for 4.2V.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You are right, reducing the voltage fixed the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Please include a schematic!!

Answer (score 1):

Provided  the PIC is in actual sleep mode and the firmware remains the same there will be no change in current consumption for a given supply voltage.

The change in supply current that you are seeing is likely to be caused by the change in supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are powering directly from a lithium battery with its too-high voltage, you might be seeing leakage current through input protection diodes, and that leakage interacting in strange ways with both the microprocessor and the external circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

If the supplying voltage is higher than 3.6v (which is only suitable for that microcontroller) there must be leakage from its protection diodes that can cause more power consumption.